# I want to a user login to centos without password on the boot process

Tags: linux, centos

Hi guys i am new to linux,

I have created a VM and configured SSH. I was thinking to start my vm as headless start and connect it with ssh from my local machine, But as soon it boot up i have get open that vm and put the login credentials then only i was able to ssh to VM. What should i do.

i want my vm to login to a user without asking for a password, so that i could able get the ssh from local machine as soon the boot process completed

Comment: do you do anything else after you login to your VM, to be able to SSH into it? Issue any commands? If your SSH service is enabled then you can login as soon as SSH service starts, there is no need to login to VM over the console. If you do 'systemctl is-enabled sshd' do you get back enabled?

Comment: no i dont need to anything. I have enabled ssh to be running after roboot. I could check the ssh status and its running after i login.